# How to receive an email whenever an PHP parse error occurs?

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

How to receive an email whenever an PHP parse error occurs?

Configuration (shared web hosting):
Linux
Apache
PHP
cPanel

Comment: `if(error) { mail(params) }`

Comment: Or a [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) handler with[`error_log($msg, 1, "email@example.org)`](http://php.net/function.error-log) even. Albeit configuring the logging daemon to send out mails would be more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

catch the error. If error exists then call the mail()